# PreDeploy.ps1 missing from tentacle directory following deployment with TeamCity and Octopus Deploy

Tags: teamcity, octopus-deploy

I have a .Net 4.5 project that I am deploying with teamcity and Octopus Deploy which includes a PreDeploy.ps1, a Deploy.ps1 and a PostDeploy.ps1.

The build action on all three is **Content**. I have tried Copy To Output Directory set to **do not copy** and **copy always**.

I can see that when TeamCity creates the nuget packages, that all three powershell scripts are included in the artifacts view. However, following the deployment, only the Deploy and PostDeploy scripts are in the octopus directory on the tentacle machine.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?  I'm still experiencing it, despite deploying a fresh new package which contains the PostDeploy.ps1 file.

Answer (score 1):

Octopus caches the downloaded packages, so perhaps you didn't bump the version number to force a fresh download? Alternatively you could check the "Re-download packages from the NuGet server" when deploying a release.

If PreDeploy.ps1 was added later than the other scripts then the above could be the reason.

Comment: I have TeamCity creating my packages and running an Octopus Integration deployment for me so the version numbers are bumped on automatically every time.

Comment: Just to make sure, I'd check the 'C:\Octopus\Applications\.Tentacle\Packages' folder to verify that the latest package was downloaded. Check the timestamp and/or open the package found here with NuGet Package Explorer to see if it contains PreDeploy.ps1.

Comment: I have checked the packages folder and cant see a package with a date stamp of 16 Dec which is the day I wrote the original question and my tidy release job has got rid of the release itself so I cant cross check. It certainly does tally up with what you are saying here, but does that means that when the team city build created the packages and stamped them with a new build number, Octopus used a cached version of the packages with a different build number? Its a bit hard to check now as I ended up putting the contents of the preDeploy.ps1 into the deploy.ps1 and that worked.

Comment: If you were able to deploy a new version of Deploy.ps1 using Octopus then caching shouldn't be the issue as a caching issue would've resulted in Deploy.ps1 not being updated.

Comment: Yes that has just occurred to me too! +1 for the help anyway.